# Can I reorder elements in map by value? C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, comparator

I want to make a table of letter frequency, just like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency)

So, I have variable `str` that contains some text, and I have `map<char, int> m`, that contains number of occurrences of each letter.

So I have something like that:

```
vector<char> get_rank(const string& str)
{
    map<char, int> m;

    for (char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
        m[i] = 0;

    for (char ch : str)
        m[ch]++;

    for (auto& it : m)
        v.push_back(it.first);
    return v;
}
```

But map is ordered by keys, not by values. Is there a way to "overload" the comparator of map to order each element by value? If the answer is no, how can I implement the same idea but with the same elegancy. Because every idea I have seems a little dull and rough.

Comment: What you're asking for makes no sense, first of all `std::map` orders/finds elements by using they key which is immutable, while the value can change, which means every value change would require the whole `std::map` to be rebalanced. Also the comparator only compares the keys, it knows nothing about the values. Maybe you just want to use `std::vector` and sort it when needed?

Comment: no, you cannot sort a map by values. It is sorted by keys. Why not make the values the keys then it is sorted as you want, no?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I thought about this idea. But it will not work because of collisions. Imagine if in my `str` there is no character `a` and `b`, thus `m[0] = a` and `m[0] = b`  at the same time.

Comment: And how do you reckon are collisions resolved when you "reorder" the map?

Comment: Please see my updated answer below. It shows many different solutions on how to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to sort a map with respect to its mapped values. The order of elements of a map is managed by the map according to its comparator which only considers keys.

However, you do not need a map to count frequencies when the keys are contiguous and of limited range.

Instead of a map, use a `std::vector<letter_and_count>` with

```
struct letter_and_count {
     char letter;
     int count = 0;
};
```

Initialize the vector with elements with `letter` initialized to `a` till `z` then increment `v[ i - 'a']` when you encounter the letter `i` in the string. Then use `std::sort` to sort the vector according to the `count` member.

PS: Note comments below. The letters `a` till `z` are not necessarily contiguous. However (idea also from eerorika) you can use a simple lookup table:

```
std::string alphabet{"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
```

Then first find the letter in that `alphabet` and use its index in the alphabet for the counting.

Comment: Note that C++ standard doesn't guarantee that character encodings map a-z contiguously and as such `i - 'a'` won't work in such cases. Old encodings exist where that is the case (EBCDIC).

Comment: @eerorika hm. Then I remember wrong. I though they are guaranteed to be contiguous. Do you know an easy way to check if they are?

Comment: That's a good idea. I thought about it too. But there's one problem with my native language. All letters in my language (russian) are not contiguous in ASCII table. from `a` to `я` codes are from -32 to -1 but I have 33 letters in my language. And that's a letter `ё` which has code -72.  I suspect that happened because letter `ё` appears in different languages. But how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @RussianStranger you should mention such things in the quesiton. Actually my answer only makes the same assumption as already your question does where `for (char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)` assumes they are contiguous

Comment: @4 A loop would work to check it. A portable solution is generate lookup table from `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`.

Comment: @eerorika lookup table is cute :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to "overload" a comparator of map to order each element by value?

No.

> If the answer is no, how can I implement the same idea but with the same elegancy.

Depends on use case. An elegant solution to the example is to sort the vector.

Answer (score 2):

I find the approach to use specialized containers very good.

For counting a `std::map` or in your case a `std::unordered_map` should be used. After that it can be copied into a `std::vector` and sorted as you like. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

// Function to get the rank of letters in a string
std::vector<std::pair<char,int>>  getRank(const std::string& str) {

    // Count letters
    std::unordered_map<char, int> counter;
    for (const char c : str) counter[c]++;

    // Copy to vector and sort
    std::vector<std::pair<char, int>> rank(counter.begin(), counter.end());
    std::sort(rank.begin(), rank.end(), [](const std::pair<char, int>& p1, const std::pair<char, int>& p2) { return (p1.second == p2.second) ? p1.first<p2.first : p1.second>p2.second; });

    return rank;
}

// Test / Driver Code
int main() {

    std::string testString{ "122333444455555666666777777788888888" };

    for (const auto& [letter, count] : getRank(testString))
        std::cout << letter << ' ' << count << '\n';
}
```

This will work in a simple way.

Usage of a `std::multiset` would make the code even more compact, because it will sort the values for you automatically:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <type_traits>

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Create aliases. Save typing work and make code more readable
using Pair = std::pair<const char, unsigned int>;

// Standard approach for counter
using Counter = std::unordered_map<std::remove_const<Pair::first_type>::type, Pair::second_type>;

// Sorted values will be stored in a multiset
struct Comp { bool operator ()(const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2) const { return (p1.second == p2.second) ? p1.first<p2.first : p1.second>p2.second; } };
using Rank = std::multiset<Pair, Comp>;
// ------------------------------------------------------------

// Function to get the rank of letters in a string
Rank getRank(const std::string& str) {

    Counter counter;
    for (const char c : str) counter[c]++;

    return { counter.begin(), counter.end() };
}

// Test / Driver Code
int main() {

    std::string testString{ "122333444455555666666777777788888888" };

    for (const auto& [letter, count] : getRank(testString)) 
        std::cout << letter << ' ' << count << '\n';
}
```

It is also possible to find the most frequent used element using a max heap.

Or, In the below example, we can get the x topmost elements. And this with just some few lines of code. The below will count nearly evrything and sortit according to the value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

// Helper for type trait We want to identify an iterable container ----------------------------------------------------
template <typename Container>
auto isIterableHelper(int) -> decltype (
    std::begin(std::declval<Container&>()) != std::end(std::declval<Container&>()),     // begin/end and operator !=
    ++std::declval<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<Container&>()))&>(),                // operator ++
    void(*std::begin(std::declval<Container&>())),                                      // operator*
    void(),                                                                             // Handle potential operator ,
    std::true_type{});
template <typename T>
std::false_type isIterableHelper(...);

// The type trait -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Container>
using is_iterable = decltype(isIterableHelper<Container>(0));

// Some Alias names for later easier reading --------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Container>
using ValueType = std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<Container&>()))>;
template <typename Container>
using Pair = std::pair<ValueType<Container>, size_t>;
template <typename Container>
using Counter = std::unordered_map<ValueType<Container>, size_t>;

// Function to get the k most frequent elements used  in any Container ------------------------------------------------
template <class Container>
auto topKFrequent(const Container& data, size_t k) {

    if constexpr (is_iterable<Container>::value) {

        // Count all occurences of data
        Counter<Container> counter{};
        for (const auto& d : data) counter[d]++;

        // For storing the top k
        std::vector<Pair<Container>> top(k);

        // Get top k
        std::partial_sort_copy(counter.begin(), counter.end(), top.begin(), top.end(),
            [](const std::pair<int, size_t >& p1, const std::pair<int, size_t>& p2) { return p1.second > p2.second; });

        return top;
    }
    else
        return data;
}
int main() {
    std::vector testVector{ 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7 };
    for (const auto& p : topKFrequent(testVector, 2)) std::cout << "Value: " << p.first << " \t Count: " << p.second << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    double cStyleArray[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3 };
    for (const auto& p : topKFrequent(cStyleArray, 2)) std::cout << "Value: " << p.first << " \t Count: " << p.second << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::string s{ "abbcccddddeeeeeffffffggggggg" };
    for (const auto& p : topKFrequent(s, 2)) std::cout << "Value: " << p.first << " \t Count: " << p.second << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    double value = 12.34;
    std::cout << topKFrequent(value, 2) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The above code is for C++17

---

And below is an example to find the most frequent element in any container.

But this is a C++20 solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

// Some Alias names for later easier reading --------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Container>
using ValueType = std::ranges::range_value_t<Container>;

template <typename Container>
using Pair = std::pair<ValueType<Container>, size_t>;

template <typename Container>
using Counter = std::unordered_map<ValueType<Container>, size_t>;

template <typename Container>
using UnderlyingContainer = std::vector<Pair<Container>>;

// Predicate Functor
template <class Container> struct LessForSecondOfPair {
    bool operator ()(const Pair<Container>& p1, const Pair<Container>& p2) { return p1.second < p2.second; }
};

template <typename Container>
using MaxHeap = std::priority_queue<Pair<Container>, UnderlyingContainer<Container>, LessForSecondOfPair<Container>>;

// Calculate max element ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Container>
auto topFrequent(const Container& data) {

    if constexpr (std::ranges::range<Container>) {
        // Count all occurences of data
        Counter<Container> counter{};
        for (const auto& d : data) counter[d]++;

        // Build a Max-Heap
        MaxHeap<Container> maxHeap(counter.begin(), counter.end());

        // Return most frequent number
        return maxHeap.top().first;
    }
    else
        return data;
}

// Test
int main() {
    std::vector testVector{ 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7 };
    std::cout << "Most frequent is: " << topFrequent(testVector) << "\n";

    double cStyleArray[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3 };
    std::cout << "Most frequent is: " << topFrequent(cStyleArray) << "\n";

    std::string s{ "abbcccddddeeeeeffffffggggggg" };
    std::cout << "Most frequent is: " << topFrequent(s) << "\n";

    double value = 12.34;
    std::cout << "Most frequent is: " << topFrequent(value) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to do something with a STL container that is clearly not designed for this (ordering a map) maybe use a different container.

You can always use `std::pair<char, int>` as the type for an `std::vector`.

These can be sorted.

I'd prefer `std::vector<std::pair<char,int>>` simply because I'm more used to working with vectors but that's up to you.

Comment: `std::ordered_set` ? You cannot rearrange order of elements in a `set`

Comment: Whoopsie... Didn't bother to check in the reference. I've fixed my mistake now :) Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: mind elaborating on how's `std::vector<std::pair<char,int>>` used in sorting by values?